# Long running celery worker task doesn't return result even after success

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, celery, rpc

I am running remote celery worker which takes around 2 hours to complete one task.
Broker I have used is rabbitmq and for backend it is rpc. After completion of task, the celery worker doesn't return result back to client.

Celery version is  4.4 and OS is windows

Can someone let me know what could be the issue as I don't see any error in celery logs.

```
pipenv run celery worker -A src.celery_app -l info -P solo

 -------------- celery@remote_host v4.4.7 (cliffs)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0 2020-09-10 20:00:18
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         celery_app:0x2191f95bb38
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://test:**@10.1.9.159:5672/test_host
- ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 64 (solo)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . doors.routes.abortDoors
  . doors.routes.pushDemToDoors

[2020-09-10 20:00:18,572: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://test:**@10.1.9.159:5672/test_host
[2020-09-10 20:00:18,595: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-09-10 20:00:19,641: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2020-09-10 20:00:19,658: INFO/MainProcess] celery@remote_host ready.
[2020-09-10 20:00:48,533: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: doors.routes.pushDemToDoors[d175239e-dcfe-4282-8596-7be80cf725fe]
```

Error logs:-

```
Task doors.routes.pushDemToDoors[697b9f66-d67e-41c0-972f-ca845212a1fb] succeeded in 9341.906000000075s: 
[2020-09-12 01:13:01,721: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Couldn't ack 1, reason:ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\kombu\message.py", line 131, in ack_log_error
    self.ack(multiple=multiple)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\kombu\message.py", line 126, in ack
    self.channel.basic_ack(self.delivery_tag, multiple=multiple)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\amqp\channel.py", line 1394, in basic_ack
    spec.Basic.Ack, argsig, (delivery_tag, multiple),
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 59, in send_method
    conn.frame_writer(1, self.channel_id, sig, args, content)
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\amqp\method_framing.py", line 189, in write_frame
    write(view[:offset])
  File "c:\users\g-us01.test\.virtualenvs\celery-z5n-38vt\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 305, in write
    self._write(s)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find this issue with option `-P gevent` in celery worker command. The culprit to connection reset issue in my case is `-P solo`.

Answer (score 0):

What is your [visibility timeout](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#visibility-timeout) setting? If your task is running longer than what is the visibility timeout setting (by default it is set to 1h), you will not get anything. To increase it to, say 4 hours, do something like `app.conf.broker_transport_options = {"visibility_timeout": 14400}` .

Comment: I ran with the visibility timeout setting to 14400, this time it failed due to connection reset error. I have updated the error logs in the question. As logs show it took 9341.906000000075 seconds to complete